# Spotify offline not working

Tags: apps

Has anyone tried using synchronized Spotify playlists in airplane mode? 
On my Nokia 930, the app is stuck at the *loading playlists' name* step.

Answer (score 3):

Try this : in the preferences of Spotify, choose the "Offline" setting and turn it on.

Might stop the infinite loading and will show your offline playlists